# How do I connect to a node.js(keystone) app on a remote host? 0.0.0.0:3000

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04, keystonejs

I want to play around with node.js a bit so I launched an Amazon ec2 micro instance. I set up node and keystone, it appears to be running:

```
------------------------------------------------
KeystoneJS Started:
My Project is ready on http://0.0.0.0:3000
------------------------------------------------
```

I've tried connecting to my app via: my-remote-ip-address:3000 but it just keeps timing out. I'm very inexperienced with the server side, what am I forgetting?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do and where this server is running. Is this a server on your local machine that you are trying to access from another machine? Is this deployed and running on AWS?

Comment: Yeah, this is deployed and running on AWS. I'm just trying to access it from a web browser. Keystone is a Node.js CMS, it should be accessible from a browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default AWS only allows incoming HTTP requests on port 80
So your request to port 3000 will time out.

You have two options:

1. Open port 3000 in the AWS console 
   Login to AWS console > goto EC2 instances > at the extreme right under security  groups click on the group to open the group linked to that particular instance. > in the tabs below select inbound > edit > add rule > type - HTTP, port - 3000, IP - anywhere or you own > save
2. In your EC2 instance use a server like nginx to internally point requests that come to port 80 to the port your node server is running on i.e. 3000 
   So you will only need to got to *my-remote-ip-address* and nginx will internally redirect the request

Comment: Thanks. This fixed it!